# Solve the following system of differential equations

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> I have to find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ knowing that: $$\begin{cases} x'= y-\int_0^tx(u)\cos(t-u)\,du \\ y'=x+\cos(t) - 1 \end{cases}$$
>   Where $x=x(t)$, $y=y(t)$ and $x(0)=1$, $y(0)=0$.

I've noticed that the integral in the first equation is the convolution between $x(t)$ and $cos(t)$, so I can apply the Laplace Transform to determine the originals $x$ and $y$.
$$\begin{cases} sF(s)-1=G(s)-F(s)\frac{s}{s^2+1} \\ sG(s)=F(s)+\frac{s}{s^2+1}-\frac{1}{s} \end{cases}$$
Is there another way to find the original functions $x$ and $y$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the Laplace Transform is fine. From your work, we have
$$\begin{cases} sF(s)-1=G(s)-F(s)\frac{s}{s^2+1} \\ sG(s)=F(s)+\frac{s}{s^2+1}-\frac{1}{s} \end{cases}$$
and by evaluating $s\cdot I+II$ we get
$$ s^2F(s)-s=F(s)+\frac{s}{s^2+1}-\frac{1}{s}-F(s)\frac{s^2}{s^2+1}$$
that is
$$s\left(s+\frac{s}{s^2+1}-\frac{1}{s}\right)F(s)=s+\frac{s}{s^2+1}-\frac{1}{s}$$
and we find that $F(s)=1/s$. Hence 
$$G(s)=\frac{F(s)}{s}+\frac{1}{s^2+1}-\frac{1}{s^2}=\frac{1}{s^2+1}.$$
Therefore $x(t)=1$ and $y(t)=\sin(t)$.

P.S. It is also easy to check that they verify
$$\begin{cases} x'= y-\int_0^tx(u)\cos(t-u)\,du \\ y'=x+\cos(t) - 1 \end{cases}$$